# Not optimized function slows down computation in parfor

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, fft

I noticed that some functions are slower in parallel computation (for each loop not for the total time) such fft calculations, and it's due to the fact that fft2 uses optimized functions that use multi-cores.

The following code shows the implemention of fft2 :

```
function [ F ] =fft_implemented(A)
% equivalent to F=fft2(A)
M=size(A,1);
N=size(A,2);
[ x, y ] = meshgrid( 0 : M - 1, 0 : M - 1 );
a1 = exp( -2 * pi * 1i / M .* x .* y );
[x, y ] = meshgrid( 0 : N - 1, 0 : N - 1 );
a2 = exp( -2 * pi * 1i / N .* x .* y );
F = a1 * A * a2;
end
```

To test this function, I used this script:

```
for i=1:5
    A{i}=rand(800,1280);
    m=A{i};
    tic
    fft_implemented(m);
    toc
end
```

The result is :

```
Elapsed time is 0.207859 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.116945 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.115507 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.115516 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.113433 seconds.
```

After using the parallel version, i found :

```
parfor i=1:5
    A{i}=rand(800,1280);
    m=A{i};
    tic
    fft_implemented(m);
    toc
end
Elapsed time is 0.941441 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.872370 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.868988 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.979503 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.004280 seconds.
```

I didn't understand why it's slower in parallel (for each loop, not for the total execution time) that in the serial case.

Comment: It seems to me that matlab uses multiple threads internally to calculate your fft implementation if you do not use `parfor`.

Comment: Are you sure that your fft2 is how MATLAB does fft2?

Comment: @ander-biguri It's the same result for fft2 and fft2_implemented